# Coordinate Geometry and Trigonometry book recommendation for GRE Math Subject Test

Tags: reference-request, soft-question, big-list, book-recommendation, gre-exam

I am currently a math major at university and I plan to take GRE Math Subject Test in future (most probably next year). Can you please suggest any good book for **revising and brushing up** Coordinate Geometry and Trigonometry topics. It would be better if the book also has **good questions** that will be helpful for practicing for the Test.

Also, are the Readings suggested at **[Problem Solving Seminar of MIT OCW](http://ocw.mit.edu/courses/mathematics/18-s34-problem-solving-seminar-fall-2007/readings/)** helpful in this regard (i.e. the subject test)?

If possible suggest **independent** books for coordinate geometry and trigonometry. Also, I would like as many suggestions as possible.

Comment: have a look at Coordinate Geometry by Loney and Trigonometry by Loney, both are classics, softcopy free available at archive.org, very cheap hardcopy available in India, both are used by students preparing for IIT entrance, very concise theory and large number of problems with answers.

Comment: We only use "Cracking the GRE Mathematics Subject Test, 4th Edition" for GRE -sub preparation. I think its enough for everything.

Comment: @YilongZhang I have read in many places that "Cracking the GRE Mathematics Subject Test, 4th Edition" is too easy compared to the actual GRE.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Problems and Solutions in Euclidean Geometry by M. N. Aref and W. Wernick" includes many theorems and exercises with some answered on Trigonometry and Euclidean Geometry.

EDIT - Maybe [this series](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1937707911) of books are suitable; I haven't read them but reviews seem pretty good and better choice if you don't want to spend a lot time. The 3rd vol. is about Geometry.

Comment: Is there anything in particular that makes the book stand out as prep for the GRE math subject test?

Comment: Actually it's a bit harder than GRE so it's worth studying it if have much time. Also if you want to receive "many suggestions" as mentioned in your edit, add "big list" in tags as well.

Comment: BTW, you maybe find some books in these questions:  http://math.stackexchange.com/search?q=GRE .

Comment: It is possible for international students. The admission process has already started for 2015-16, I think in the beginning of June, (after declaration of results of 10+2). If you want to join in this academic year, you should contact them asap. For Indian students, admission is on basis of merit, maybe it is the same for International students (you better confirm from them). I don't have idea about the fees applicable for foreigners. But since admissions are going on, it is best for you to contact them. I hope it was helpful...:)